# Exception in Application start method java with fxml

Tags: javafx, fxml

So i made pretty simple application with Fxml with only label and text field, and two buttons but i get this error..

Exception in Application start method

And here is code

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8*?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?> 

<GridPane alignment="CENTER" hgap="5.0" vgap="5.0">
    <children>
        <Text text="Dodavanje Kupca" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnSpan="2">
        <font>
          <Font size= "30.0"/> 
        </font>
    </Text>
    <Label text="Ime Kupca" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="2"/>
    <Label text="Prezime Kupca" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="3"/>
    <Label text="Adresa Kupca" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="4"/>
    <Label text="Email Kupca" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="5"/>
    <Label text="Telefon Kupca" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="6"/>
    <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2"/>
    <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3"/>
    <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4"/>
    <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="5"/>
    <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="6"/>
<HBox alignment="TOP_RIGHT" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="7">
    <children>
        <Button mnemonicParsing="true" text="Save"/>
        <Button mnemonicParsing="true" text="Clear"/>
    </children>
</HBox>
    </children>

    <padding>
        <Insets bottom="16.0" left="15.0" right="15.0" top="15.0"/>
    </padding>
</GridPane>
```

And here is the main class:

```
package main;
import java.net.URL;
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class test extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    URL fxmlUrl= getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("view.fxml");
    GridPane root= FXMLLoader.<GridPane>load(fxmlUrl);

    Scene scena = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scena);
    stage.show();

    }
}
```

Sorry.
Here is another edit for stack trace.
Stack trace is little too big so again ill type some non sense here

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2504)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at main.test.start(test.java:20)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[10,22]
Message: A pseudo attribute name is expected. 
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.setInputSource(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:214)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.<init>(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:184)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLInputFactoryImpl.getXMLStreamReaderImpl(XMLInputFactoryImpl.java:262)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLInputFactoryImpl.createXMLStreamReader(XMLInputFactoryImpl.java:134)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2478)
    ... 17 more
Exception running application main.test
C:\Users\Djordje Zlatic\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

Comment: Post the main class in the question (not as an answer), along with the complete [stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/2775450).

Comment: Where is the stack trace?

Comment: This looks weird: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8*?>` (3rd char from end)... Should be `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Comment: True i fixed it but still same thing  same error

Comment: I made that change and it worked fine afterwards. Make sure you have saved the file and that it is being redeployed to the build folder.

Comment: i made that change saved everything and checked if its in right folder, /src/main/ and stil nothing i am definitely doing something wrong

Comment: As I said, check that it is being properly deployed to the build folder.

Comment: Yeah thanks its working!